# In WP8 how to find position for a control relative to the second control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have this page

```
<ViewportControl x:Name="Viewport" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" SizeChanged="Viewport_SizeChanged">
     <Grid>
         <Image x:Name="Image1" Stretch="Uniform" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
         <Image x:Name="SeconImg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
     </Grid>
</ViewportControl>
```

And I need to know position SeconImg relative Image1

Example: [image]
How can I know this position? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your relative position like this:

```
GeneralTransform myTransform = SeconImg.TransformToVisual(Image1);
Point relativePosition = myTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

relativePosition has `X` and `Y` properties which you can read then.

`TransformToVisual(UIElement visual)` is a motehod of class `UIElement`, which allows you to read a position of any UIElement relative to other UIElement. For example you can read relative position to LayoutRoot (Grid).

Comment: relativePosition.X and relativePosition.Y always return 0. If I set `Point relativePosition = myTransform.Transform(new Point(1, 1));` they return 1

Comment: @Std_Net As I've tested it, I don't have such problems and always get right value. A little strange - your images top left corners aren't over each other?

Comment: Image1 stretch to grid Image2 have size 100x100 and horizontal and vertical alignment = center and I use ViewportControl maybe problem here?

Comment: @Std_Net Can you see your images? I think there is something wrong with your Viewport - if I define its Bounds or its Height (and width) or Height (and width) of grid inside, everything works ok.

Comment: Sorry. all work excellent. I just restart my VS and PC and all work ))))